# Can't access ViewDataDictionary object properly on StringTemplate

Tags: viewdata, stringtemplate

I'm playing with StringTemplate version 3.1.4.6002 as a view engine for an MVC project. I can't seem to access an object being passed to the template and have it render on a webpage. So basically, I have the the following in the controller (in C#):

```
var layer1 = new { count = "1", label = "Description" };
var layer2 = new { count = "2", label = "Transcription" };
ViewData["layers"] = new object[] {layer1,layer2};
```

On the view file test.st, I have:

```
$layers:{
   $it.count$
   $it.label$
}$
```

The template does not display anything on the webpage, but if I do this on the test.st:

```
$layers$
```

it displays the object as:

```
{ count=1, label=Description } { count=2, label=Transcription }
```

which looks like to me a string. So how do I access just the count and the label independently? I've googled a lot already and can't seem to find anything that would fix my problem.

By the way, I'm using Visual Studio V10 and .NET Framework Version4. On the project I have References to Antlr3.Runtime, Antlr3.Runtime.Debug and  Antlr3.StringTemplate dlls. Also, I have no problems accessing simple string objects. I've used the tutorial project in [here](http://websitelogic.net/articles/mvc/stringtemplate-viewengine-asp-net-mvc/2). I can supply more details if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the count and label fields public or, if they are getters, are they public?

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me to the right direction. I converted the anonymous types layer1, layer2 and layer3 to objects with internal access and with public fields and now I can see the values on the webpage! By the way, I am just discovering StringTemplate and I'm really sold to its simplicity. We have been using XSLT at work and that has a massive learning curve I remember. I might post new questions in the future as I use it. Keep up the excellent work!